# do not optimize/remove html

Tags: wysiwyg, theming

I would like to have a page with some html content in it that CK Editor does not seem to support, in particular: I want to have a little `<form` tag with a couple of `<input` fields. I can enter it in `Switch to plain text editor` mode and save from there and it will keep the elements but when I want to `edit` the page, it'll go back to the `Switch to rich text editor` and remove my `<form` html items. How can i set CD Editor to not remove any `html` it may not be able to render? 
Thank you!

Comment: That's not a good way to do forms in Drupal. You should use the Webform module for drupal which has a nice admin interface and is more secure than what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Beebee I'm using `Webform` already for my email and contact forms but this is a form with which I want to submit data to some other `php` script, not for emailing...

Comment: then you should get this addon module: [Webform Remote Post](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_remote_post) which should fulfill your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which one you are using (filter or full html) You need to go to

/admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html

OR

/admin/config/content/formats/full_html

[image]

Then under Limit Allowed html Tags add `<form> <input>` into the list.

If that does not do it, try unchecking the correct faulty and chopped off html box.

**Edit:**

If you want to switch between text formats and not have your code erased go to:

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Advanced (for Filter HTML)

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full (for Full HTML)

Then under Advanced Content Filter, select disabled.

[image]

Comment: Even when **Correct faulty and chopped off HTML** is unchecked, as soon as I hit **Switch to rich text editor** followed by **Switch to plain text editor** my `form` html gets removed. Also, there's no **Limit allowed HTML tags** as I'm using the **Full HTML** format

Comment: humm yes, switching does cause it to go blank. umm I guess you'll have to use the CKeditor "Source" button.

Comment: nvm that doesn't work either.

Comment: I think I found the solution, I edited my answer

Comment: This is still a very bad practice to do forms this way through the text editor.