# CKeditor and Panels

Tags: 7, panels, theming, wysiwyg

I'm having trouble getting the styles applied using CKeditor to render on field output. While all the styles from the site's main CSS are available when editing the text in CKeditor, the only style changes that seem to stick are the basic ones (em, strong, etc.) For example, on this site, there is a Bio field for users, which has been Panelized. I want users to have all the styles from the CSS to play with; the problem is that WYSI ***not*** WYG right now, unless you stay on the admin pages.

Originally, I thought it was just Panel pages, but it's showing up on a least one node. I can't find the recipe that causes it, but the problem is reliably on the same pages/nodes.

I have tried:

- removing/reinstalling CKeditor
- removing WYSIWYG module
- installing the WYSIWYG module and disabling the CKeditor module (the WYSIWYG module never would detect that the CKeditor library was installed, no matter what version I used... and yes, I checked the WYSIWYG Compatibility Matrix.)
- reinstalling the StyleSheetParser plugin for CKeditor
- using Stylizer (I want the user to specify the style, not to have a generic style for all in that field)

This is basically the last thing I need to do on this site before I move it over to the client's host and do training/hand-off. It's driving me crazy!!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. If I did, I believe you just need to add tags to the limit allowed HTML tags field. [see my answer to another question.](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173475/do-not-optimize-remove-html/173479#173479) Might be what you're looking for.